# Is there a way to cache database entries for specific users in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.8

So I'm helping to make a Flask API for an app that will allow users to share the creations they make on the app with others. One of the things we want to implement is a way for users to sort by the newest creations uploaded to the server. Currently, we just have the API sort the results by the time they were uploaded, and paginates those results.

The problem is, if a user makes a request to get page 1 of the newest creations, and stays there long enough for more to be uploaded to the server, before going to page 2, some creations may be pushed back, leading the user to see the same thing more than once. What would be the best way to get around this?

Sorry if this is unclear, or if the title is inaccurate. I'm having a hard time putting this issue into words, so I would be happy to try and clarify if needed.

Comment: I will note that many sites (including this one!) have exactly that problem, and don't attempt to work around it. Unless someone is really spamming your app with new content, it's only ever going to be a minor inconvenience. You could maintain some sort of state (e.g., id of last seen content) and use that to limit the results from the database, but that might prove tricky or not very performant in practice.

Comment: To prevent this, some sites load the data dynamically client-side. So while your user is browsing, more will appear at the top without them having to reload the page. This won't solve the problem, but will make the user understand why they're getting the same things on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

A potential workaround is cursor-based pagination. In most pagination issues, ask `give me 10 items, starting from item number 100`, and you'd get a SQL query like so

```sql
SELECT *
FROM posts
...
ORDER BY posted_at DESC
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 100
```

This query gets all posts, orders them, subtracts the first 100 values, and then applies a LIMIT to get only 10 rows. Now, if there are a lot of new posts, this might lead to a post popping up on page 1, and then when you go to page 2, you see the same post again. Why? There's a new post in the database, pushing this one to the 11th place, and thus to page two. Another issue is that is becomes slow for farther pages (say 100, 1000).

With cursor based pagination, you remove the ability to go to a specific page, and only allow people to go to the *next* or the *previous* page. The difference is that you send the `posted_at` date of the last item on the page with the request, which essentially becomes `give me the first 10 items posted before date x`.

In SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM posts
...
WHERE posted_at < '2020-09-01 00:00:05'
ORDER BY posted_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

There is one small problem with this. If two posts are posted at *exactly* the same time, the person might miss one, if it's number 11 on page 1 and gets cut off, but it's not strictly *smaller* than the `posted_at` date of post 10.

A workaround is to use `id`s, if you can guarantee that they are always increasing. So if having a higher ID means *always* that it's also newer, then you can do this. Otherwise, you can also use the combination of `id` *and* `posted_at`. This way it doesn't matter whether `id`s are increasing, since it makes the order deterministic. What I mean is that if you have two posts with the same posted_at time, but B has a higher `id` than A, it will always be shown on the next page if A is the last on this page. The SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM posts
...
WHERE (posted_at < '2020-09-01 00:00:05'
   OR (posted_at = '2020-09-01 00:00:05' AND id > 1500))
ORDER BY posted_at DESC, id
LIMIT 10
```